# error: data location must be storage or memory for parameter in funtion but none was given solidity

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Election{
  //model a candidates
  struct candidate
  {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint votecount;
  }
  //store candidates
  //fetch candidate

  mapping(uint => candidate) public candidates;

  //store candidate count

  uint public candidatescount;

  function () Election public {
    addcandidate("candidate1");
    addcandidate("candidate2");
  }
  function addcandidate (string _name) private
  {
    candidatecount ++;
    candidates[candidatescount] = candidate(candidatescount, _name, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `string` is dynamically-sized type, modern version of Solidity compiler require location to be explicitly specified like this:

```
function addcandidate (string memory _name) private
```

or

```
function addcandidate (string storage _name) private
```

For your purpose `memory` looks more relevant.

In both cases, `_name` is passed by reference, but in the former case the reference is address in memory, while in the latter case the reference is address in storage.